# No shipping description in order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipping-methods

I have an issue with orders, to be specific with shipping method description.

I've noticed that sometimes shipping description in 'Shipping and Handling Information' tab appends as: 'No shipping information available'.

It doesn't happen in all orders, and I haven't found any pattern yet.

I've tried to track down where the problem is, but all I've found is that some orders have an empty `shipping_description` column in 'sales_flat_quote_address' table, whereas `shipping_method` column is always correct.

I've tried to find **getShippingDescription()** or **setShippingMethod()**  methods implementation, but I got lost and it did not result in anything.

I'm using SolvingMagento OneStepCheckout module.

In:  app/code/local/Solvingmagento/OneStepCheckout/controllers/OnestepController.php in submitOrderAction() method:

```
$results[] = $this->saveShippingMethodData($shippingMethod, false);
```

Then we have:

```
protected function saveShippingMethodData($shippingMethod, $response = true)
{
    $result = $this->getOnestep()->saveShippingMethod($shippingMethod);

    if (isset($result['error'])) {
        if ($response) {
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
            return false;
        }
    }
    $this->getOnestep()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);

    return $result;
}
```

then in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php we have:

```
    public function saveShippingMethod($shippingMethod)
{
    if (empty($shippingMethod)) {
        return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
    }
    $rate = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRateByCode($shippingMethod);
    if (!$rate) {
        return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
    }
    $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
        ->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);

    $this->getCheckout()
        ->setStepData('shipping_method', 'complete', true)
        ->setStepData('payment', 'allow', true);

    return array();
}
```

And now I have no clue where it is going, I can not find any **saveShippingMethod()** implementation.

Could anyone help me to get back on tracks with solving this issue?
What could be wrong or where should I be looking?

I'd appreciate any help.

**Possible fix:**

I belive the problem was caused by my own modification of OneStepCheckout module. I tried to load each sections (billing info, shipping, payment etc.) automatically (without the need to click on anything) and that seemed to be the problem. Sometimes new record in sales_flat_quote_address just did not appear, so I've added the following line into my js file:

```
shippingMethod.getStepUpdate.bindAsEventListener(this, false);
```

That line forces the script to create a new row filled with default data. And now it works fine.

Take that in mind, my solution might be diffrent than yours, as it was caused by me and not faulty module.

I'd advice you to take a closer look at _sales_flat_quote_address (especially shipping_method and shipping_description column), becouse I belive it is connected to this problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Same problem i am facing,any fix ?

Comment: Possible solution above.

Comment: I am using onepage checkout and also done few modification in checkout module,when i check the console during the checkout progress, the request http://.../checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/
Post parameter for shipping_method is showing correct.
what u think the cause of problem here ?
b'z for few orders this problem coming
thanks

Comment: @RahulSingh As I said, look at  #_sales_flat_quote_address table. Check if shipping_method and shipping_description column is filled correctly and at what moment during checkout process new rows are being created.

Comment: Yes,I have checked #_sales_flat_quote_address table
for few orders shipping_method is filled but shipping_description is null, the same problem you faced,but also one thing i noticed for few orders both  
shipping_method, shipping_description column is null.Its strange

Comment: any possible solution to fix this ?
thanks

Comment: Well, I'd recommend you to debug this file: app/code/local/Solvingmagento/OneStepCheckout/controllers/OnestepController.php, especially at submitOrderAction. Try to find out if shipping method data is still present at this stage. If you won't find any error yet, you can go deeper and take a look at saveShippingMethod() at app/code/local/Solvingmagento/OneStepCheckout/Model/Type/Onestep.php. This method is called from OnestepController and it is directly responsible    for getting shipping_description

Comment: I am using the onepage checkout and debugged the OnepageController.php file,used the log file and tried to find Shipping method save action data,here its showing the correct data in log.The main issue is that this problem doesn't happen in all orders,and till now unable to reproduce this case.
any idea how to reproduce the case ?
thanks

Comment: Since we don't know the cause, I have no idea how to reproduce the case :|

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find the solution? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where I need to add shippingMethod.getStepUpdate.bindAsEventListener(this, false); code? In which file?

Comment: I am getting the same issue but I cant understand where I need to add your mention code.  Can you please help me with it. So I can fix the issue on my site as well.

Comment: @Indian I have this code in my custom javascript file, but the point is just to execute this line of code as soon as dom is ready (I use jquery ready method).

Comment: If you don't mind can you please provide me that code? I really need it. I try to resolve this issue for 3 days but not getting any success.

Comment: @Indian Of course, `jQuery(document).ready(function(){shippingMethod.getStepUpdate.bindAsEventListener(this, false);});`. This is located in separate js file.

Comment: @br33f I tried the Same thing but it's not working. Sometimes shipping description entry not save in sales_flat_quote_address table.  Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Any solution for this issue? i am facing the same issue.